# How upgrade the default Remmina at Ubuntu Desktop 22.04?

Tags: apt, upgrade, remote-desktop, vnc, remmina

Having Ubuntu Desktop `22.04`, was confirmed through `Ubuntu Software` that [Remmina](https://remmina.org/) is installed *by default* with the version `1.4.25+dfsg`, it has sense according with the [How to install Remmina](https://remmina.org/how-to-install-remmina/) page that shows `1.4.25` for this distribution, the unique difference is `+dfsg`

In the same URL you can see there are higher versions.

**Question**

- How upgrade `Remmina` in Ubuntu Desktop?

Is it possible? And Yes, I already did do `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`.

**Reason**

I want to connect to other OS distribution, for example Fedora 37 which it uses `1.4.29` - So I am not sure if `1.4.25+dfsg` is compatible with `1.4.29` or not - and if not I want to know how upgrade. And of course, assuming the new releases have patches and new features.

**Extra Question**

- What does `+dfsg` mean?

Comment: "*I want to connect to other OS distribution, for example Fedora 37 which it uses 1.4.29*" The version on another release seems irrelevant, since Remmina is merely a client, not a server. You won't be connecting two Reminnas.

Comment: 'dfsg' usually means that the upstream source has been patched by Debian developers to omit non-free code.

Comment: Older release = Older software. Explained in [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software) The bottom line is that if you want newer software, you should use a newer release of Ubuntu or use a Snap package.

Comment: You don't need Remmina in the remote computer, such as Fedora 37, or another Ubuntu. **So it does not matter which version of Remmina the Fedora has.** To use Remmina in Ubuntu, to connect to another computer, you need to specify which protocol you want to use, and make sure that the server for that protocol is installed in the remote computer (eg Fedora).

Comment: Yes, agree about the versions of `Remmina` between OS - it was a confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the Snap or Flatpak Version (1.4.29 (git v1.4.29)) from the [Snap-Store](https://snapcraft.io/remmina) or [Flathub](https://beta.flathub.org/de/apps/org.remmina.Remmina).

Comment: Can I install directly? or Should I uninstall first the current version?

Comment: @ManuelJordan Yes you can but i would uninstall the older version if everything works